# C++ call function on vector elements, derived from the vectors' base class

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

At the moment, I'm trying to write a GUI system on top of SFML. Now, I'm also implementing simple widgets. Each has a vector of pointers to sf::Drawables (just a base class for all drawable objects). In that vector, all components of the widget are stored (for example a sf::Text object as a title, a sf::ConvexShape object for a button shape and so on).

Now I want to iterate through all components and, on EACH OBJECT POSSIBLE, call a function named 'getGlobalBounds' for mouse checking. The problem is, not all sf::Drawable derivings have this function (for example, sf::Text doesn't). How can I call this function on every object which has a implementation of this function?

Comment: Assuming an inheritance hierarchy, use dynamic_cast.  But this smacks of a bad design.

Comment: I don't think you can without putting in an extra layer of abstraction or some really dodgy work with `dynamic_cast`

Comment: `sf::Text` **does** provide [`getGlobalBounds()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Text.php#a95d732f58bd12bf7ec388b106f3729ba)

Comment: Oups, you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As you can see here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Sprite.php), it's the `sf::Sprite` class that provides the `getGlobalBounds` function.

So you want to iterate your vector and pick out all the elements that subclass this, and call the function on them:

```
std::vector<sf::Drawable *> items;
for (sf::Drawable *item : items)
{
    sf::Sprite *maybeSprite = dynamic_cast<sf::Sprite*>(item);
    if (maybeSprite != nullptr) // Cast succeeded
    {
        maybeSprite->getGlobalBounds();
        ...
    }
}
```

---

That said, as mentioned in the comments this isn't an ideal design. Maybe you could keep a vector of pointers to `sf::Drawables` which is a superset of the pointers in a vector of pointers to `sf::Sprites`, and add items to one or both depending on their type. Then you only need to iterate over the items you **know** provide the function, and you might be able to avoid the nasty `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: One can write the cast and test a little more compact: `if(auto maybeSprite = dynamic_cast<sf::Sprite*>(item)){ maybeSprite->getGlobalBounds(); }`

Comment: @zett42 I know, it's just personal preference that I write it like this - it makes the conditional and declaration distinct, so easier to grok.

Comment: I personally find the shorter variant easier to read because I can immediately recognize the pattern. As you said, a matter of personal preference.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the original problem, because `sf::Sprite` is a very specific derived class not inherited by other drawables. This way you'd only draw all `sf::Sprite`s but nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using dynamic_cast, a traditional SFINAE solution would be -

```
template <class T>
struct has_getGlobalBounds
{
    template <class U>
    static auto foo(U &u) -> decltype(u.size());
    static char foo(...);
    T t;
    static const bool value = !std::is_same<char, decltype(foo(t))>::value;
};

template<class T>
typename enable_if<!has_getGlobalBounds<T>::value, void>::type call_getGlobalBounds(const T& t)
{}

template<class T>
auto call_getGlobalBounds(const T& t) -> decltype(t.getGlobalBounds())
{
    return t.getGlobalBounds();
}
```